# New To MySql Nested Query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables that I'm trying to pull data from:

- USER
- USER_NAME

USER has the following indexes:

- ID
- ORG_ID
- DEFAULT_EMAIL_ID
- STATUS
- NAME
- CREATED
- UPDATED

USER_NAME has the following indexes:

- ID
- USER_ID
- STATUS
- TIMEZONE_ID
- DST
- LANG
- USERNAME
- PASSWD
- BACKEND
- REGISTERED

My goal is to get USERNAME from USER_NAME and NAME from USER.
My background is more in DB2. I'm just learning MySQL.
I tried the following with no luck.

select NAME from OST_USER where ID in (select ID, USERNAME from OST_USER_ACCOUNT where CREATED < '2015-07-09');

Any idea what I can do to get the info? Is it even possible with the given indexes? Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: You should add sample data and expected results. Also it seems that solution will come from using INNER JOIN over USER_ID field.

Comment: I assume that when you say "indexes" you mean "columns" from tables called `USER` and `USER_NAME`. Your attempt includes a table called `OST_USER_ACCOUNT` that you don't describe. You also set a criteria for the variable `CREATED` that is undescribed. Please clarify!

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to select username from USER_NAME table that has the same USER_ID as ID in USER table, then your query must look:

```
SELECT USER.NAME, USER_NAME.USERNAME 
FROM USER, USER_NAME 
WHERE USER.ID = USER_NAME.USER_ID
```